# Crystal lang : How to indicate require path for crystal compiler

Tags: crystal-lang

If some of my libraries locate out of default directory `lib`, could I indicate the require path to compile successfully without `lib` directory nor `shards.yml`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, change the `CRYSTAL_PATH` environment variable. By default it's `$CRYSTAL_ROOT/src:lib` (the `src` directory of the installation, and then the relative `lib` directory). Just add `:some_other_dir` at the end of that.

Example: `CRYSTAL_PATH=$CRYSTAL_ROOT/src:lib:~/my_lib_dir`

Comment: Does this still expected to work in `Crystal 0.32.0`? Not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work as mentioned in another answer, this won't work `CRYSTAL_PATH=$CRYSTAL_ROOT/src:lib:~/my_lib_dir`.

Because in my case the `CRYSTAL_ROOT` was blank.

The solution was to execute `crystal env` and copy from there whatever paths it has for `CRYSTAL_PATH` and then re-set it as `CRYSTAL_PATH=whatever-paths-you-just-copied:~/my_lib_dir`